# How can I structure a REST API endpoints for MS Web Api cleanly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I have a data model called PIM (Product Info Manager) that requires that I pass a company AppId for every request. So if I want to get all the products I would pass a Company AppId and the resource id.

I'm trying to structure my REST endpoints in a clean manner and I've come up with this:

```
http://api.example.com/pim/44/products/    -- Gets all products in company 44
http://api.example.com/pim/44/products/123 -- Get product 123 in company 123
```

Is this the best way to implement this?

I was planning making my default controller `pim/{appId}/{controller}/{id}`

Will I run into problems with my MVC routes if I do this?
How do I access the {appId} token in my GET method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have the route as you described, and use it

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default",
    routeTemplate: "pim/{appId}/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And in your controller you'd have the following methods:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public Product Get(int appId, int id) { ... }
    public List<Product> Get(int appId) { ... }
}
```

Since the parameter names (appId, id) match the route parameters, ASP.NET Web API should bind the URL value to the parameter when the operation is called.

Comment: Fantastic! Simple and to the point! Convention over configuration. Love it.